# AWK - How would I modify my AWK script to ignore the lines within a file that do not contain a matching pattern?

Tags: awk

I have a **text** file that contains data in the following format. This is a sample of the data it contains. The file is correct and in the correct format:

```
 <node id="1647008557" lat="36.6536840" lon="-121.7938995" version="1" timestam  p="2012-02-25T14:03:54Z" changeset="10787766" uid="294728" user="skew-t">
  <tag k="highway" v="turning_circle"/>
  </node>
  <way id="10459706" version="2" timestamp="2010-03-27T18:21:32Z" changeset="4247030" uid="20587" user="balrog-kun">
    <nd ref="89705976"/>
    <nd ref="89798118"/>
    <nd ref="89798120"/>
    <nd ref="89798122"/>
    <nd ref="89798124"/>
    <nd ref="89798126"/>
    <nd ref="89798128"/>
    <nd ref="89798130"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Engineer Road"/>
    <tag k="tiger:cfcc" v="A41"/>
    <tag k="tiger:county" v="Livingston, CA"/>
    <tag k="tiger:name_base" v="Engineer"/>
    <tag k="tiger:name_type" v="Rd"/>
    <tag k="tiger:reviewed" v="no"/>
    <tag k="tiger:separated" v="no"/>
    <tag k="tiger:source" v="tiger_import_dch_v0.6_20070809"/>
    <tag k="tiger:tlid" v="196844016"/>
  </way>
  <way id="10461171" version="3" timestamp="2014-01-07T00:17:59Z" changeset="19855176" uid="1871178" user="RBoggs">
    <nd ref="89804458"/>
    <nd ref="89804460"/>
    <nd ref="89804463"/>
    <nd ref="89804464"/>
    <nd ref="89804466"/>
    <nd ref="89804468"/>
    <tag k="access" v="no"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
    <tag k="motor_vehicle" v="no"/>
    <tag k="name" v="5th Cutoff Street"/>
    <tag k="tiger:cfcc" v="A41"/>
    <tag k="tiger:county" v="Marysville, CA"/>
    <tag k="tiger:name_base" v="5th Cutoff"/>
    <tag k="tiger:name_type" v="St"/>
    <tag k="tiger:reviewed" v="no"/>
    </way>
<way id="151860745" version="1" timestamp="2012-02-25T14:03:59Z" changeset="10787766" uid="294728" user="skew-t">
    <nd ref="1647008614"/>
    <nd ref="1647008545"/>
    <nd ref="1647008605"/>
    <nd ref="1647008555"/>
    <nd ref="1647008557"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="service"/>
  </way>
```

And I am trying to print out the `name` within the `way id` section along with the `way id` itself, the sequence number the `nd ref` is at, and the `nd ref` id.

Like so in the **correct output**:

```
$ awk -f table.awk file.txt | head
road,way_id,seq_num,node_ref_id
Engineer Road,10459706,1,89705976
Engineer Road,10459706,2,89798118
Engineer Road,10459706,3,89798120
Engineer Road,10459706,4,89798122
Engineer Road,10459706,5,89798124
Engineer Road,10459706,6,89798126
Engineer Road,10459706,7,89798128
Engineer Road,10459706,8,89798130
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,1,89804458
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,2,89804460
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,3,89804463
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,4,89804464
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,5,89804466
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,6,89804468
```

How would I print that output by ignoring the lines that do not contain `<tag k="name"` within the `<way>` tag?

Comment: Response: don't use awk to parse xml, check my answer...

Comment: Now since your edit, your XML is broken. Better post a question with all 'materials' and explanations than expanding post/sample input over time

Comment: It's frustrating for people taking time to answer you correctly.

Comment: We will not encourage you to do dirty things. Fix your XML, then use a real XML parser

Comment: How would I go about even fixing the XML when that is the exact file given to me in a text file format? The file is called `file.txt` and I am only trying to get the output from it with `awk`, not modify it.

Comment: There's a problem to escalate to fix it then. If it's broken, someone or something break it

Comment: I don't understand why the file is broken. The data is presented with the `<way id` tag for every segment, it is just that some of those segments do not have a `<tag k="name"` which is what I am trying to ignore.

Answer (score 2):

Don't parse XML/HTML with awk, use a proper XML/HTML parser and a powerful [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) query.

#### theory :

According to the compiling theory, XML/HTML can't be parsed using regex based on [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Due to hierarchical construction of XML/HTML you need to use a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) and manipulate [LALR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) grammar using tool like [YACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc).

#### realLife©®™ everyday tool in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

You can use one of the following :

[xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) often installed by default with `libxml2`, xpath1 (check [my wrapper](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/xmllint) to have newlines delimited output

[xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) can edit, select, transform... Not installed by default, xpath1

[xpath](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath) installed via perl's module XML::XPath, xpath1

[xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) xpath3

[saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) my own project, wrapper over @Michael Kay's Saxon-HE Java library, xpath3

#### or you can use high level languages and proper libs, I think of :

[python](/questions/tagged/python)'s [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) (`from lxml import etree`)

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl)'s [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod), [`XML::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath), [`XML::Twig::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig), [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath)

[ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) [nokogiri](/questions/tagged/nokogiri), [check this example](https://sputnick.fr/scripts/parsing-HTML-with-NokogiriXpath.rb.html)

[php](/questions/tagged/php) `DOMXpath`, [check this example](https://sputnick.fr/scripts/parsing-HTML-with-DOMXpath.php.html)

---

Check: [Using regular expressions with HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

---

#### Example using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

Use this, based on [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) :

### File :

(before OP changed XML for a broken one)

```
  <way id="10459706" version="2" timestamp="2010-03-27T18:21:32Z" changeset="424 7030" uid="20587" user="balrog-kun">
    <nd ref="89705976"/>
    <nd ref="89798118"/>
    <nd ref="89798120"/>
    <nd ref="89798122"/>
    <nd ref="89798124"/>
    <nd ref="89798126"/>
    <nd ref="89798128"/>
    <nd ref="89798130"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Engineer Road"/>
    <tag k="tiger:cfcc" v="A41"/>
    <tag k="tiger:county" v="Livingston, CA"/>
    <tag k="tiger:name_base" v="Engineer"/>
    <tag k="tiger:name_type" v="Rd"/>
    <tag k="tiger:reviewed" v="no"/>
    <tag k="tiger:separated" v="no"/>
    <tag k="tiger:source" v="tiger_import_dch_v0.6_20070809"/>
    <tag k="tiger:tlid" v="196844016"/>
  </way>
```

### Code :

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='|' read title id < <(
    xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//tag[@k="name"]/@v' -o "|" -v '//way/@id' file
)
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//nd/@ref' file | while read line; do
    echo "$title,$id,$((++c)),$line"
done
```

### Output :

```
Engineer Road,10459706,1,89705976
Engineer Road,10459706,2,89798118
Engineer Road,10459706,3,89798120
Engineer Road,10459706,4,89798122
Engineer Road,10459706,5,89798124
Engineer Road,10459706,6,89798126
Engineer Road,10459706,7,89798128
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. But, is there a way to get the same output using `awk`?

Comment: awk is not an xml parser

Comment: Nice answer. I would suggest: `xmlstarlet  sel -t -m '/way/nd'  -v '../tag[@k="name"]/@v' -o , -v '../@id' -o ,, -v '@ref' -n file.xml | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$3 = NR} 1'` -- using xmlstarlet's `-m` "match" expression to "loop" over the nd tags. Perhaps less efficient as it has to look up the name and id every time, but only a single call to xmlstarlet

Comment: @Gilles Isn't it possible to get the output with awk since the file I am using it with is a text file? Does awk have a function I can use to get the number at where the node_ref_id appears in my file?

Comment: `while read line; do
    echo "$title,$id,$((++c)),$line"
done` can be written to run orders of magnitude faster (and more robustly since it won't interpret escape sequences) as `awk -v title="$title" -v id="$id" -v OFS=',' '{print title, id, NR, $0}'` but I was assuming the OP had multiple `<way>...</way>` blocks in his real input and idk how you'd handle that with the current xmlstarlets+post-processing approach.

Comment: Removed one call to xmllint, just having two now

Answer (score 0):

"Gilles Quenot" already told you to use a proper XML/HTML parser and he mentions Xidel is one of them.
I've saved your XML file as '*so_49592301.xml*'.

The legend, as a string, is easy:

```
$ ./xidel -s so_49592301.xml -e '"road,way_id,seq_num,node_ref_id"'
```

Next you select the `<way>` element node, but only those that hold a `<tag>` child node with the attribute `k="name"`:

```
$ ./xidel -s so_49592301.xml -e '"road,way_id,seq_num,node_ref_id"' -e '//way[tag[@k="name"]]'
```

Next you select the `<nd>` child node and do a string join on the index and the `ref` attribute, with a comma as separator:

```
$ ./xidel -s so_49592301.xml -e '"road,way_id,seq_num,node_ref_id"' -e '//way[tag[@k="name"]]/nd/join((position(),@ref),",")'
road,way_id,seq_num,node_ref_id
1,89705976
2,89798118
3,89798120
4,89798122
5,89798124
6,89798126
7,89798128
8,89798130
9,89804458
10,89804460
11,89804463
12,89804464
13,89804466
14,89804468
```

Notice the index doesn't start over with the next `<way>` element node? This can easily be fixed by putting `nd/...` between parenthesis:

```
$ ./xidel -s so_49592301.xml -e '"road,way_id,seq_num,node_ref_id"' -e '//way[tag[@k="name"]]/(nd/join((position(),@ref),","))'
road,way_id,seq_num,node_ref_id
1,89705976
2,89798118
3,89798120
4,89798122
5,89798124
6,89798126
7,89798128
8,89798130
1,89804458
2,89804460
3,89804463
4,89804464
5,89804466
6,89804468
```

Next you include the `v` attribute from the `<tag k="name">` child node and the `id` attribute from the `<way>` element node. You're inside the `<nd>` child node however, so to include stuff 1 level higher you have to prepend `../`:

```
$ ./xidel -s "so_49592301.xml" -e '"road,way_id,seq_num,node_ref_id"' -e '//way[tag[@k="name"]]/(nd/join((../tag[@k="name"]/@v,../@id,position(),@ref),","))'
road,way_id,seq_num,node_ref_id
Engineer Road,10459706,1,89705976
Engineer Road,10459706,2,89798118
Engineer Road,10459706,3,89798120
Engineer Road,10459706,4,89798122
Engineer Road,10459706,5,89798124
Engineer Road,10459706,6,89798126
Engineer Road,10459706,7,89798128
Engineer Road,10459706,8,89798130
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,1,89804458
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,2,89804460
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,3,89804463
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,4,89804464
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,5,89804466
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,6,89804468
```

And to make it more readable:

```
$ ./xidel -s "so_49592301.xml" \
> -e '"road,way_id,seq_num,node_ref_id"' \
> -e '//way[tag[@k="name"]]/(
>       nd/join(
>         (
>           ../tag[@k="name"]/@v,
>           ../@id,
>           position(),
>           @ref
>         ),
>         ","
>       )
>     )'
road,way_id,seq_num,node_ref_id
Engineer Road,10459706,1,89705976
Engineer Road,10459706,2,89798118
Engineer Road,10459706,3,89798120
Engineer Road,10459706,4,89798122
Engineer Road,10459706,5,89798124
Engineer Road,10459706,6,89798126
Engineer Road,10459706,7,89798128
Engineer Road,10459706,8,89798130
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,1,89804458
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,2,89804460
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,3,89804463
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,4,89804464
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,5,89804466
5th Cutoff Street,10461171,6,89804468
```